# string comparion like a,b,c with c, b, a

Tags: excel

I have 2 data tables with three columns empname, empid and  role 
want to compare both table by column "role" to check whether common employee in both sheets as different role or not .

i want to flag exception role wise( i.e common employee of both tables have different roles)
e.g of data tables

table 1

```
EmpName        EmpID        Role
Aakash C Shah   id1        user, auditor
Abdul Yasin     id2        Password Admin,Password Admin,Group Admin
Abhijit Chakre  id3        Group Admin,Password Admin
Abhijit Dixit   id4        Group Admin,DC Admin
```

table 2

```
Emp Name        EmpID        Role
Aakash C Shah   id1      auditor,password Admin, DC Admin
Abdul Yasin     id2      Group Admin,Password Admin,Password Admin
Abhijit Chakre  id3      Password Admin,Group Admin
Abhijit Dixit   id5      DC Admin,Group Admin
```

i m facing below issue
1) exact match of string is not happening for "role" column as we can see employee with empID id 2 and id 3 are same but still exceptions are coming since sequence of role in the cell is different .i.e
in table 1 it starts with password admin and in table 2 it starts with group admin
similar is the case with id 3.it should come not as exception .

exception should be emp - Aakash C Shah with id1 as it has different role in both sheets    .
My approach was

1. split the string into array
2. sorting of array
3. concatenation of string- newcolumn (say 4)
4. output should come when table1(col 4) <> table 2(col4) for same employee.

but i was doing through macro recording.Can anyone help with vba code at least for 1 and 2 point .

```
<Option Explicit

Sub compare()

Dim shtold As Worksheet, shtnew As Worksheet, shtmatch As Worksheet
Dim oldrow As Long
Dim newrow As Integer
Dim I As Integer, id, f As Range

Application.Cursor = xlDefault

          I = 2



Set shtold = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("sheet1")
Set shtnew = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("sheet2")
Set shtmatch = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("sheet3")

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

     For oldrow = 2 To 10

    id = Trim(shtold.Cells(oldrow, 5))

    Set f = shtnew.Range("E2:E5").Find(id)

    If f Is Nothing Then

    With shtmatch.Rows(I)
        .Cells(1).Value = shtold.Cells(oldrow, 1)
        .Cells(2).Value = id
        .Cells(3).Value = shtold.Cells(oldrow, 2)


    End With

    I = I + 1
    End If
  Next oldrow

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
MsgBox "Finished", vbInformation, "Done!"

  End Sub>
```

- Inputs

sheet1

```
EmpName        EmpID       Role3
Aakash C Shah   id1       id1auditoruser
Abdul Yasin     id2       id2group adminpassword adminpassword admin
Abhijit Chakre  id3       id3group adminpassword admin
Abhijit Dixit   id4       id4dc admingroup admin
```

sheet2

```
EmpName         EmpID   role3
Aakash C Shah   id1     id1auditordc adminpassword admin
Abdul Yasin     id2     id2group adminpassword adminpassword admin
Abhijit Chakre  id3     id3group adminpassword admin
Abhijit Dixit   id5     id5dc admingroup admin
```

output( expected) -

```
EmpName           EmpID       Role3
 Aakash C Shah    id1         id1auditoruser
```

AS it is different from sheet2

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please show any code/formulas you've attempted, and describe what works/doesn't work.

Comment: i have used this function for splitting but it is not working

Comment: Function splitup(mystring As String, mysep As String, Optional vertical As Boolean = False) As Variant
    
    Dim newarray() As String
    Dim j As Integer
    Dim i As Integer
    
    x = ((Len(mystring) - Len(Replace(mystring, mysep, ""))) / Len(mystring)) + 1
    ReDim newarray(x - 1) As String
    
    For i = 1 To x
    If Len(mystring) - Len(Replace(mustring, mysep, "")) = 0 Then
    
    newarray(i - 1) = mystring
    Exit For
    
    End If

Comment: j = 1

For j = 1 To Len(mystring)

If Mid(mystring, j, Len(mysep)) = mysep Then

newarray(i - 1) = Mid(mystring, 1, j - 1)
mystring = Mid(mystring, j + Len(mysep), Len(mystring))
Exit For
End If
Next j
Next i

If vertical Then

splitup = Application.Transpose(newarray())
Else
splitup = newarray()

End If

End Function

Comment: i was thinking to apply the function on column to get array .but it didnt work

Comment: @KusumSirole When you write code in a comment, it is not useful, as you should have seen.  Please edit your original question in order to add the code blocks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a UDF that will return a sorted string based on input of a comma-separated string.  As written, it is case insensitive so the result will be converted to all lower case, for comparison purposes.

With such short lists to be sorted, probably any sort routine can be used; I chose a Quicksort because it was handy in my library.

The code demonstrates both splitting, and sorting and concatenation of the array, so it answers your questions 1, 2 and 3.

```
Option Explicit
Option Compare Text 'case insensitive
Function sortCSS(str As String) As String
    Dim sArr() As String
    Dim I As Long

sArr = Split(str, ",")

'Remove the spaces
For I = 0 To UBound(sArr)
    sArr(I) = Trim(sArr(I))
Next I

Quick_Sort sArr, 0, UBound(sArr)

sortCSS = LCase(Join(sArr, ","))

End Function

Sub Quick_Sort(ByRef SortArray As Variant, ByVal first As Long, ByVal last As Long)
Dim Low As Long, High As Long
Dim Temp As Variant, List_Separator As Variant
Low = first
High = last
List_Separator = SortArray((first + last) / 2)
Do
    Do While (SortArray(Low) < List_Separator)
        Low = Low + 1
    Loop
    Do While (SortArray(High) > List_Separator)
        High = High - 1
    Loop
    If (Low <= High) Then
        Temp = SortArray(Low)
        SortArray(Low) = SortArray(High)
        SortArray(High) = Temp
        Low = Low + 1
        High = High - 1
    End If
Loop While (Low <= High)
If (first < High) Then Quick_Sort SortArray, first, High
If (Low < last) Then Quick_Sort SortArray, Low, last
End Sub
```

Here is the output given your tables:

[image]

However, I would set up to do this using Dictionaries and Classes, but that's just me and a personal preference.

Comment: thanks , its working and very easy to use ,only one word +one click will get result.

Comment: By using your UDF I changed the column to compare both sheets (Please refer code above ) trying to get exception  ( I.e rows which are not matching ) . But not getting Correct output. As this is just 4 row i have 10000 of rows to compare where in role can be repetitive hence i am concatenating ID with role since ID is unique for each employee .

Comment: @KusumSirole I don't understand what you are doing, or why. I don't understand why you need to concatenate the ID, and you have not shown how you are using the results of my formula in anything.  All you need to figure out who, in Table 1, is also in Table 2, but with different roles, are relatively simple worksheet formulas.  I suggest you start a new question, and provide an example of what you are doing to get the output you require (as well as an example of your data, and where you are getting an incorrect result, whatever you mean by that).

Answer (score 0):

It seems that at a minimum you have an assortment of delimiters separating your values, incorrect/non-consistent capitalization, duplication of roles within one employee, mismatched roles between tables and unsorted data.

Before sub procedure:

[image]

Sub procedure:

```
Option Explicit

Sub repairRoles()
    Dim vTBLs As Variant, vVAL1 As Variant, vVAL2 As Variant
    
    vTBLs = Array("Table1", "Table2")
    
    With Worksheets("sheet4")
        vVAL1 = .ListObjects(vTBLs(0)).DataBodyRange.Columns(3).Value2
        vVAL2 = .ListObjects(vTBLs(1)).DataBodyRange.Columns(3).Value2
        sort_Correct_Homogenize_Dedupe vVAL1, vVAL2
        .ListObjects(vTBLs(0)).DataBodyRange.Columns(3) = vVAL1
        .ListObjects(vTBLs(1)).DataBodyRange.Columns(3) = vVAL2
    End With
End Sub

Sub sort_Correct_Homogenize_Dedupe(ByRef val1 As Variant, ByRef val2 As Variant, Optional delim As String = ", ")
    Dim v As Long, j As Long, k As Long, tmp As Variant, discard As Variant
    
    For v = LBound(val1, 1) To UBound(val1, 1)
        val1(v, 1) = Replace(val1(v, 1), Chr(44), Chr(44) & Chr(32)) & Chr(44) & Chr(32) & _
                     Replace(val2(v, 1), Chr(44), Chr(44) & Chr(32))
        val1(v, 1) = Application.Trim(val1(v, 1))
        tmp = Split(val1(v, 1), Chr(44) & Chr(32))
        For j = LBound(tmp) To UBound(tmp) - 1
            For k = j + 1 To UBound(tmp)
                If Mid(tmp(j), 2, 1) = LCase(Mid(tmp(j), 2, 1)) Then tmp(j) = StrConv(tmp(j), vbProperCase)
                If Mid(tmp(k), 2, 1) = LCase(Mid(tmp(k), 2, 1)) Then tmp(k) = StrConv(tmp(k), vbProperCase)
                If tmp(k) < tmp(j) And tmp(k) <> vbNullString Or tmp(j) = vbNullString Then
                    discard = tmp(j)
                    tmp(j) = tmp(k)
                    tmp(k) = discard
                ElseIf tmp(k) = tmp(j) Then
                    tmp(k) = vbNullString
                End If
            Next k
        Next j
        Do While tmp(UBound(tmp)) = vbNullString: ReDim Preserve tmp(UBound(tmp) - 1): Loop
        val1(v, 1) = Join(tmp, delim)
        val2(v, 1) = Join(tmp, delim)
    Next v
End Sub
```

After sub procedure:

[image]

I'm willing to answer specific questions in comments but you should do your own research first.

Comment: its typical to understand but finally got it, thanks for guiding.